# SQL Server: How to tell if a database is a system database?

Tags: sql-server-2005, information-schema

I know that so far (until MSSQL 2005 at least), system databases are master, model, msdb and tempdb.

Thing is, as far as I can tell, this is not guaranteed to be preserved in the future. And neither the sys.databases view nor the sys.sysdatabases view tell me if a database is considered as a system database.

Is there someplace where this information (whether a database is considered a system database or not) can be obtained?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just dived into `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database` object (which is provided by Microsoft itself!)
They simply do this using following statement:

```
CAST(case when dtb.name in ('master','model','msdb','tempdb') 
   then 1 
   else dtb.is_distributor end AS bit) AS [IsSystemObject]
```

In short: if a database is named `master`, `model`, `msdb` or `tempdb`, it IS a system db;
it is also a system db, if field `is_distributor = 1` in the view `sys.databases`.

Hope this helps

Jimmy

Comment: Jimmy caught what others missed. When you've got replication enabled, SQL Server adds an additional system database named 'distribution'.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Management Studio uses this

if you expand "System Databases" in "Object Explorer" (seen from wireshark):

```
SELECT dtb.name AS [Database_Name]
FROM master.sys.databases AS dtb
WHERE (CAST(case when dtb.name in ('master','model','msdb','tempdb') then 1 else dtb.is_distributor end AS bit)=1)
```

For the sake of simplicity I removed irrelevant columns, removed orderby and replaced @_msparam_0 variable by its value 1

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on the DB_ID() function <= 4

You'd have to work very hard to change this...

Comment: This is not true.  If you have distributor database, then it will have an id > 4 and it is a system db.

Comment: Also, in Azure SQL Database user databases start at ID 4, not 5.

Answer (score -5):

owner_sid is equal to 0x01 just for system databases.
So you can use it to recognise if the database is a system DB or not.

```
select * from sys.databases
where owner_sid != 0x01
```

Comment: This isn't a good idea, since it will return any database owned by `sa`, system or not.

Comment: This does not work in Sql Azure, where the master db will have sid other than 0x01.

Comment: See https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/database-owners/ - sa should be owner of all databases, and better the login itself is disabled.

Answer (score -6):

no there's no such option AFAIK. i guess you could check the id the sys.databases.owner_sid = 0x01.

i don't think you have to worry about MS changing the system db names. if they did theat you wouldn't have to worry about it for at least 20 years :)