# Is it possible to query the system databases in SQL server without using the names?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, system-databases

When doing a query over several databases in SQL server (2005+) I find it sometimes necesary to exclude the system database (master, model, tempdb, msdb and distribution)

Is there any OTHER way to filter these besides

```
where name not in (''master', 'model', 'tempdb', 'msdb', 'distribution')
```

I've looked at sys.databases and master.dbo.sysdatabases (not the same!)

[UPDATE] an example query which I use to look for databases that have logshipping enabled

```
select d.name, p.last_backup_date, s.secondary_server, s.secondary_database
from sys.databases d
    left outer join msdb..log_shipping_primary_databases p on p.primary_database = d.name
    left outer join msdb..log_shipping_primary_secondaries s on s.primary_id = p.primary_id
where name not in ('model','master','tempdb','distribution','msdb')
order by d.name
```

[UPDATE] This seems to be the 'least bad' way, unless someone else has a better way?

```
SELECT * FROM 
master.sys.databases AS dtb 
WHERE (dtb.database_id < 5 or dtb.is_distributor = 1)
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of what queries you're running?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran SQL Profiler and refreshed the system databases node in management studio. It uses the query

```
...FROM
master.sys.databases AS dtb
WHERE
(CAST(case when dtb.name in ('master','model','msdb','tempdb') 
then 1 else dtb.is_distributor end AS bit)=1)
```

So I guess you could combine the `dbid` and `is_distributor` checks.

Answer (score 3):

There is no safe means beyond searching on the name. If you only wanted to filter out the four main databases (master, model, msdb, tempdb), you can safely filter on `DBID > 4`. However the distribution database will get a DBID like a normal database and thus you cannot rely on its DBID.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed the distribution DBID as well, it's the underlying reason for my question.

Answer (score -1):

```
select
    *
from
    sys.databases
where
    name in ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')
    or is_distributor = 1
```

Comment: question clearly states "Is it possible to query the system databases in SQL server without using the names?" , also same (deleted)  answer you posted here several years after the fact: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819095/sql-server-how-to-tell-if-a-database-is-a-system-database