# Shrinklog all user databases in SQL2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi   I am using this script in the process of weekly maintenance, suggest best approach/scripts to do shrinklog. Currently am getting an error with the below script

```
declare @s nvarchar(4000)
set @s= '
        if ''?'' not in (''tempdb'',''master'',''model'',''msdb'') 
        begin
            use [?] 
            Alter database [?] SET Recovery simple
        end '

exec sp_msforeachdb @s
set @s= '
        if ''?'' not in (''tempdb'',''master'',''model'',''msdb'') 
        begin     
            use [?]  
            Declare @LogFileLogicalName sysname
            select @LogFileLogicalName=Name from sys.database_files where Type=1
            DBCC Shrinkfile(@LogFileLogicalName,1) 
        end'
exec sp_msforeachdb @s
```

Error Description:

> ShrinkLog Execute SQL Task     Description: Executing the query "declare @s nvarchar(4000)  set @s= '        ..." failed with the following error: "Option 'RECOVERY' cannot be set in database 'tempdb'.  Cannot shrink log file 2 (DBServices_Log) because total number of logical log files cannot be fewer than 2.  DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

note: I am avoiding tempdb(all System db) in my script, but error message shows tempdb?

Comment: Do you get the error when you run it manually in a normal query window instead of from a scheduled job?

Comment: It is scheduled to run through SQL ServerAgent job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the worst maintenance script I've seen in the past year. A maintenance script that every week **breaks the log chain** and makes the database unrecoverable?? OMG. Not to mention that the simple premise of shrinking the log on a maintenance task is wrong. If the database log has grown to a certain size, than that size is needed. Schedule log backups more frequently to prevent this, but don't *schedule* log shrink operations.

Comment: Am appriciate your suggestion, want to know what is the wrong with this script.

Comment: Two things are wrong: 1) `Alter database [?] SET Recovery simple` will break the log chain of any database *not* in simple recovery. and 2) The premise of the script is wrong, that you need to shrink the logs periodically. Logs are kept small by taking frequent log backups (if not already in simple recovery mode). Shrinking is an extraordinary operation done only on special occasions, **never** on a regular scheduled maintenance.

Comment: Please look at the note and respond,

Comment: about the note: certain validations are done at compile time, not at execution time. So even though your batch contains `ALTER DATABASE [tempdb] SET RECOVER ...` in an IF branch that is never *executed*, it is still compiled and the error 5058 is raised.

Comment: I do not know Why I got -ve mark, Please let me know,anything wrong

Comment: I have this exact scenario.. for my test server.. I dont do log backups for my test database, but I need to restore from our live server (which has db's in full recovery)... so.. i want to nightly make sure all my db's are in simple (again.. my test server)... any ideas on how to avoid the error?

Comment: @Rob: ask a separate question, explaining your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the 5058 error by using an exec statement to alter the database recovery model.  The following script will set each user database to a simple recovery model.  (It uses [Jimmy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9682659/1882616) to detect system databases.)

```
exec sp_msforeachdb 'if exists (select name from sys.databases d where case when d.name in (''master'',''model'',''msdb'',''tempdb'') then 1 else d.is_distributor end = 0
    and name = ''?'' and recovery_model_desc != ''SIMPLE'')
begin
    declare @previousRecoveryModel varchar(100) = (select recovery_model_desc from sys.databases where name = ''?'');
    print ''Changing recovery model for ? from '' + @previousRecoveryModel + '' to SIMPLE.'';
    use master;
    -- Using exec avoids a compile-time 5058 error about tempdb, which is a branch that will never be executed in this code.
    exec (''alter database [?] set recovery simple'');
end';
```

Then you won't get the compile-time error about tempdb because the exec statement will compile its statement with the database name variable already substituted.