# How to use 'use' command across all database to execute certain script in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a certain script which I need to execute across all databases in SQL Server. I have used the following logic to loop through all database excluding the system databases.

```
declare @DBName varchar(500)
DECLARE @Database_id  int
DECLARE @Query        varchar(MAX)
select @Database_id = MIN(database_id) from sys.databases where      database_id>4
while @Database_id is not null
begin
select @DBName=name from sys.databases where database_id=@Database_id
set @Query = 'Use'+@DBName 
            --some script
            Print ''+@DBName+''
            exec (@Query)
select @Database_id = MIN(database_id) from sys.databases where  database_id>4 AND database_id>@Database_id 
end
```

But the problem is I can't use the 'Use' command with a variable. Is there any other way to make use of 'Use' command to hit the database?

And I don't want to use `sp_MSforeachdb` command as my query is too long.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to run the script on all DBs in the instance or just a specific DB provided by the user executing the SP?

Comment: I would like to run in all DBs in the instance

Comment: I would like to run the script in all DBs except for system DBs.

Comment: Is this question solved?

Answer (score 1):

There is an undocumented function doing this. You can use the question mark in the place of the db's name:

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; EXEC sp_spaceused'
```

Find this example and more explanations here: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx

EDIT: From your comments above I find, that you do not want to includ the system dbs into your run. It seems to be q bit tricky to detect, whether a db is a system db or not but you could go like this:

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(1000)='USE [?];IF DB_ID(DB_NAME())<=4 RETURN;EXEC sp_spaceused;'
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb @cmd;
GO
```

Read about the flaws here (about SQL Server 2005!): [SQL Server: How to tell if a database is a system database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1819095/5089204)

If you don't like this `<=4` you could simply do it like

```
IF DB_NAME() IN('master','model',... any more names here ... ) RETURN;
```

The only real restriction I know of is, that sp_MSforeachdb does not like "GO".

Comment: Thanks Shunugo but I really don't want to use sp_MSforeachdb. If I'm not mistaken it has certain limit for any query to relate to it.

Comment: @SujanEmmanuel Don't know what "certain limit for any query" means for you, but otherwise you should probably use dynamic SQL and a CURSOR. I'll do an EDIT to my answer in some minutes...

Comment: @Shugo How to overcome if there is a GO statement? Is there any other   solution for this?

Comment: @SujanEmmanuel I'm afraid there isn't. Even dynamic SQL will not allow you to call `EXEC (@AStatementWithGO)`. You'll have to break your SQL into separate batches and call them one after the other...

Comment: @SujanEmmanuel, Sorry, I did not look into your code carefully enough... If you want to continue with your code you might just concatenate the `USE <dbName>` directly at the start of your `@Query` variable within your loop. But this will not solve the "GO"-problem...

Comment: Yes. I'm bit of a newbie, so how exactly you mean concatenate USE <dbName> in my  @Query variable.

Comment: @SujanEmmanuel, Looking again more closely - I saw a tiny thing which could produce your problem: `set @Query = 'Use'+@DBName` . Shouldn't be a space after the "Use"? If you pass something like `USE dbName; DoMore;` to `EXEC` it should work...

Comment: @SujanEmmanuel, please let me know, I'm so curious :-) Was it the space after the USE ?