# Indexing same table in multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have almost 150 databases with all the same tables. I know its bad but I don't have control over it. I'm trying to improve performance with some indexes. I know what the indexes should be but I need to build them on the same tables in every database. Is there a way to do this bsides creating them all separately?

Comment: Create script for index creation and use sp_msforeachdb kinda procedure to run it an all databases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use 'use' command across all database to execute certain script in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329248/how-to-use-use-command-across-all-database-to-execute-certain-script-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar situation a while back so I came up with this code.  You can use dynamic SQL with `sp_MSforeachdb` to loop through your databases. I've excluded the system databases below but you can include/exclude databases as you like in that first `IF`.

This code will check each database for your specific table as well as checking to see if that index already exists on that table.  If not, it creates it.  I included a `RAISERROR` to show the progress through the databases in SSMS messages.  Just change the table/index names below and update the `CREATE INDEX` statement as appropriate for you.

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
SELECT @command = 'IF ''?'' NOT IN(''master'', ''model'', ''msdb'', ''tempdb'') 

    BEGIN USE ? 
       EXEC(''
   
           DECLARE @DB VARCHAR(200)
           SET @DB = DB_NAME()
           RAISERROR (@DB, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT

           IF OBJECT_ID(''''dbo.TableName'''', ''''U'''') IS NOT NULL
           BEGIN
               IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.indexes WHERE name=''''IX_TableName'''' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID(''''TableName''''))
               BEGIN
                    CREATE INDEX [IX_TableName] ON TableName (indexColumn)
               END
           END

       '') END' 

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```