# T-SQL - Trying to query something across all databases on my server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I've got an environment where my server is hosting a variable number of databases, all of which utilize the same table structures/schemas. I need to pull a sum of customers that meet a certain series of constraints with say, the user table. I also need to show which database I am showing the sum for.

I already know all I need to get the sum in a db by db query, but what I'm really looking to do is have one script that hits all of the non-system DBs currently on my server to grab this info.

Please forgive my ignorance in this, just starting out.

Update-
So, to clarify things somewhat; I'm using MS SQL 2014. I know how to pull a listing of the dbs I want to hit by using:

```
SELECT  name
FROM    sys.databases
WHERE   name not in ('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb')
AND state = 0
```

And for the purposes of gathering the data I need from each, let's just say I've got something like:

```
select count(u.userid)
from users n
join UserAttributes ua on u.userid = ua.userid
where ua.status = 2
```

New Update:
So, I went ahead and added the ps sp_foreachdb as suggested by @Philip Kelley, and I'm now running into a problem when trying to run this (admittedly, I can tell I'm closer to a solution). So, this is what I'm using to call the sp:

```
USE [master]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_foreachdb]
        @command = N'select count(userid) as number from ?..users',
        @print_dbname = 1,
        @user_only = 1

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

This provides a nice and clean output showing a count, but what I'd like to see is the db name in addition to the count, something like this:

|[DB_NAME]|[COUNT]|

But for each DB

Is this even possible?

Comment: is it one database replicated (in that case the data in all of them suppose to be simillar) or different databases with different data?

Comment: What do you mean by a non-system DBs exactly?
also, You should post some code to indicate what you already know and what you are missing.
Help us help you ;-)

Comment: (Assuming SQL Server) Are there multiple databases within a single instance of SQL Server, multiple instances of SQL Server, or both? Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: @user2033402 - all data is similar. Each db belongs to a specific client, and we're trying to audit the number of users within each of their db that has certain permissions

Comment: @DaniDev - I mean to exclude dbs like I would in the below:

    SELECT  name
    FROM    sys.databases
    WHERE   name not in ('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb')
 AND state = 0

Comment: @HABO - Sorry about that. This is for SQL Server 2014

One server, multiple databases

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate the databases from schema / sysdatabases. At least in situations without replication, excluding db_ids 1 to 4 as system databases should be reasonably robust:

```
SELECT [name] FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE dbid NOT IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Other methods exist, see here: [Get list of databases from SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147659/get-list-of-databases-from-sql-server) and here: [SQL Server: How to tell if a database is a system database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819095/sql-server-how-to-tell-if-a-database-is-a-system-database)

Then prefix the query or stored procedure call with the database name, and in a cursor loop over the resultset of the first query, store that in a sysname variable to construct a series of statements like that:

```
SELECT column FROM databasename.schema.Viewname WHERE ...
```

and call that using the string execute function

```
EXECUTE('SELECT ... FROM '+@@fully_qualified_table_name+' WHERE ...')
```

Comment: Relying on the `sid` column from `master.dbo.sysdatabases` is not necessarily going to give you "all 'system' databases." It will give you "all databases that are owned by the 'system'." I'd love to know if there is an ideal way to do this but the only predictable one I've come across is hard coding the ids 1-4.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 me too. all methods around seem to be hacks like going by names, which is not safe in replication-enabled topologies, and going by sid or db_id... see also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819095/sql-server-how-to-tell-if-a-database-is-a-system-database)

Comment: I'd highly recommend against relying on owner simply because setting the owner of a database to `sa (0x01)`  is relatively common regardless of whether it's a good practice or not. Relying on the name or id is also imperfect but the odds of someone renaming system databases is much lower in comparison. I personally tend towards relying on the id simply because there's no way to change it via the GUI (unlike name).

Comment: agreed, and updated answer accordingly. if the OP had a possibility to mark his "non-system databases" with some property unique to them only, might be best practice.

Comment: The user-defined flag certainly isn't any worse than using magic numbers or strings. You'd think that such a field would be built-in by now...

Answer (score 1):

*Source Code:* https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113063/executing-dynamic-sql-programmatically

*Example Usage:*

```
declare @options int = (
    select a.ExcludeSystemDatabases
    from dbo.ForEachDatabaseOptions() as a
);

execute dbo.usp_ForEachDatabase
    @Command = N'print Db_Name();'
  , @Options = @options;
```

`@Command` can be anything you want but obviously it needs to be a query that every single database can understand. `@Options` currently has 3 built-in settings but can be expanded however you see fit.

I wrote this to mimic/expand upon the `master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb` procedure but it could still use a little bit of polish (especially around the "logic" that replaces `?` with the current database name).

Answer (score 0):

There’s the undocumented sytem procedure, sp_msForEachDB, as found in the master database. Many pundits on the internet recommend not using this, as under obscure fringe cases it can be unreliable and somehow skip random databases. Count me as one of them, this caused me serious grief a few months back.

You can write your own routine to provide this kind of functionality. This is a common task, however, and many people have already done it and posted their code online… so why re-invent the wheel?

@kittoes0124 posted a link to “usp_ForEachDatabse”. This probably works, though pro forma I hate any stored procedures that beings with `usp_`. I ended up with Aaron Bertrand’s utility, which can be found at http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/.

Install a version of this routine, figure out how it works, plug in your script, and go!

Comment: Much appreciated. I am somewhat leery of using sp_msForEachDB for many of the reasons you mention. I'll check this out

Comment: @PhilipKelley While your hatred for the convention is totally understandable it's a red herring that has absolutely nothing to do with the code. My aliasing conventions are even more abhorrent (a, b, c...) but the abstract nature generally allows you to swap in whatever you personally prefer. I would truly like to know what you use in place of `usp_`.

Comment: We use nothing--no set of "prefix" characters. We name stored procedure names based on their function. Context is almost always sufficient to identify that a given string of characters is a stored procedure, and not a table, column, trigger, or other database object.