# TSQL List Result based on date in name field minus GETDATE() function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In our QA environment we restore databases for Developers and then drop them if the restore was done > 30 days. The naming convention for these restored databases are MyCompany-HA_DBName_20191114_FirstL.

I need to create a script to drop the database that are older than 30 days and run this script via SQL Agent job everyday to find and drop databases older than 30 days. However, my concern is that there are other databases with similar naming convention (does not include date in their name) that will get deleted. I have excluded all important databases in my query in where clause but I'm concern with new database that will be added to the server that should not be deleted.

I need help with returning only databases with date in their name which are older than 30 days. I have so far created the below query but it is not returning some databases. I used the like operator but something is not correct.

Any help is appreciated.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ListofDbsToDrop') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #ListofDbsToDrop
SELECT * INTO #ListofDbsToDrop 
FROM ( 
SELECT * FROM SYS.DATABASES 
WHERE DATABASE_ID > 4 --Exclude sys databases.
AND  GETDATE() - CREATE_DATE > 30 --Return databases created more than 30 days ago.  
AND NAME LIKE  'CompanyName-HA%[_]%%[99999999]%%[_]%%[A-Z][a-z]%'
AND NAME NOT IN (  --Exclude important databases. 
'MyCompany-HA_DBName',
'MyCompany-HA_DBName2'
)) AS ListofDatabases

Select * from #ListofDbsToDrop 

I will place drop database loop here.
```

Comment: For debugging filters it can be helpful to change the the query so that it doesn't filter, but returns the filter conditions as columns, e.g. `select *, case when Database_Id > 4 then 1 else 0 end as [Database_Id Check], case when GetDate() - Create_Date > 30 then 1 else 0 end as [Create_Date Age], ... from Sys.Databases;`. Have a look at the individual columns and that should help you spot the error.

Comment: Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819095/sql-server-how-to-tell-if-a-database-is-a-system-database) for the more appropriate logic to avoid "system" databases. Use of database_id is common but flawed.

Comment: And you really should get OUT of the habit of using math on date or datetime values. Rather - use "create_date < dateadd(day, -30, getdate()). Not that it matters in this instance, but this logic is sargable whereas your logic is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a string.  Assuming the parts before the date have no digits, you can get the date using this string manipulation:

```
convert(date, left(stuff(name, 1, patindex('%[0-9]%', name) - 1, ''), 8))
```

Then you can compare directly to something like `dateadd(day, -30, getdate())` for your filtering.

If you have databases that don't follow this pattern, use `try_convert()`:

```
try_convert(date, left(stuff(name, 1, patindex('%[0-9]%', name) - 1, ''), 8))
```

Comment: Thanks for this but when I use your code in Like operator the query does not return any result. Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

AND NAME LIKE  'convert(date, left(stuff(name, 1, patindex(''%[0-9]%'', name) - 1, ''), 8))'

Comment: @Ali . .  Huh?  Your question is about comparing dates.  You would compare the name using `like`.

Comment: Yes I wanted to compare the date in the Name field. Can you please guide me how i can do that? So basically what I'm looking for is if the date in the name of database is greater than 30 days then return that database in query result.

Comment: @Ali . . . This answers the question.  I mean, it extracts the date from the name.  You just need to add the comparison.

Comment: Thanks, It works on my laptop but not working on the server: 

SELECT Name, convert(date, left(stuff(name, 1, patindex('%[0-9]%', name) - 1, ''), 8)) AS RestoredOn
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE DATABASE_ID > 4 --Exclude sys databases. 
AND convert(date, left(stuff(name, 1, patindex('%[0-9]%', name) - 1, ''), 8)) < dateadd(day, -10, getdate())

I get this error: 
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Completion time: 2019-11-22T11:43:56.9451053-07:00

Any idea why? I tried using cast but not working.